# libpng 1.5.10 error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, libpng

```
png_read_info (png_ptr, info_ptr);
{ 
    png_byte color_type = info_ptr->color_type;
    png_byte bit_depth  = info_ptr->bit_depth;
    ...
```

For last 2 lines I get

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

What's wrong? In libpng 1.4 this was always ok.

Comment: This means you have not included the proper headers.

Comment: @Shahbaz `png.h` are included. `-I/usr/include/libpng15` exist.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `png_info` struct was removed from the `png.h` in 1.5.0 and now you should use this pointer with the `png_get_*` and `png_set_*` functions.

As specified in [libpng manual](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt):

> The png_info structure is designed to provide information about the
>   PNG file.  At one time, the fields of png_info were intended to be
>   directly accessible to the user.  However, this tended to cause
>   problems with applications using dynamically loaded libraries, and as
>   a result a set of interface functions for png_info (the png_get_*()
>   and png_set_*() functions) was developed, and direct access to the
>   png_info fields was deprecated..

For example:

```
png_uint_32 height;
height = png_get_image_height( png_ptr,  info_ptr);
```

Comment: don't exists functions `png_get_width`, `png_get_height`. how to get `info_ptr->height`, `info_ptr->width`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set contents of info_ptr which is no longer directly accessible, use png_set_IHDR()

As specified in [libpng manual](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-4.3)